# How can I download pictures from a URL to a local computer without asking permission?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm developing an Instagram ATM machine, which let users search for their photos by a username or hashtag. After selecting the images and paying, they would get a printed copy. For that purspose I'm using HTML, PHP, Javascript and Jquery.

Here's my problem, I have an URL for each picture selected by the user, example:

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23279358_143343893084349_1681002671546302464_n.jpg

To be able to print the pictures, I need to download them to the local computer, without asking permission (in the background). Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `file_get_contents($url)` will get you the data, which you can then manipulate as a variable, or save locally with `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: You're setting up a service where you charge for other people's photos?

Comment: Saving files to a user's computer without asking permission is a security risk, and is therefore not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `download` attribute to force download and JS to automatically click that link.

```js
document.getElementById('download').click()
```

```html
<a href="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/23279358_143343893084349_1681002671546302464_n.jpg" download id="download">Download begins</a>
```

Comment: JS automatically clicks that link, but I still have the "save as" window.

Comment: @Robarrer it's browser dependent based on security settings

Comment: Thank you very much, very noob here. I had to add an extension to get rid of the download bar below, now is working perfectly